# Can magnetic resonance through TV and cell phones control your mind and emotions?

Tags: electromagnetism, emotions, mind-control

I saw [this picture on FB with 1,200 likes and 9,738 shares](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1129052010438125&set=gm.1753141688249370&type=3&theater)

[image: Facebook picture]

The graphic reads,

> GOOGLE THIS NUMBER: **US6506148 B2**
>   IT'S NO LONGER A CONSPIRACY THEORY... YOUR TELEVISION IS BRAINWASHING TOOL USED TO MANIPULATE YOU.

I assume they want the google patent to show up when you Google for US6506148 B2. That [patent for US6506148 B2](http://www.google.com/patents/US6506148) reads *"Nervous system manipulation by electromagnetic fields from monitors"*.

Further you can find this claim and reference to this patent repeated by Alex Jones. [In this video, Alex Jones says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lwoAXjcnCA)

> "[Lithium in the water is] child's play compared to thousands of patents, most of them US government, dealing with electromagnetics through cell towers, through tv towers, through cell phones, where they can module and make you throw up, make you become giddy, make you have an aphrodisiac, make you die, make you have a heart attack."

Alex Jones goes on to say,

> "They are also getting ready to deploy towers that put off a magnetic resonance that will calm people during emergencies."

Comment: Why would the U.S. Government need (or want or register for or have any use for) a patent, especially one for such a nefarious purpose?

Comment: Also that patent refers (in text and pictures) to display screens using older CRTs ("tubes"). For one thing, CRTs were never used on cell phones.

Comment: Why, yes.  TV screens emit light, which is an electromagnetic field.  Advertisers pay TV broadcasters billions of dollars for access to them in order to manipulate viewers into buying their products.  (Or voting for them, &c.)

Comment: It's true.  They're manipulating your thoughts and emotions using EM radiation in the 400THz-800THz region.  The fiends!  And it's not just old CRT displays.  They've been constantly improving the sophistication of this manipulative technology.

Answer (score 15):

There's a bunch of claims and half-truths combined with some misapplied truths.

First: Yes, electromagnetic waves can influence the nervous system. There are, for example, highly experimental treatments of Parkinson's and Tourette's using little electric pulse-givers embedded into the brain:
http://www.parkinson.org/understanding-parkinsons/treatment/surgery-treatment-options/Deep-Brain-Stimulation

In addition: http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/could-certain-frequencies/

That article has a lot of good examples for how EM radiation can affect the brain. From that article:

> Magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) of the living brain uses an
>   externally imposed magnetic field. Preliminary findings suggest that
>   bipolar-disorder patients moods improve immediately after they undergo
>   a specific MRI procedure. It is possible that this effect works in a
>   way similar to that of TMS on symptoms of depression, but further
>   investigation is warranted.

However, the magnetic fields in an MRI device are incredibly high compared to what your TV, microwave, cellphone can put out. That's why you have to remove all metal prior to having an MRI scan done.

EM radiation can "mess" with your brain though:
http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/mind-control-by-cell/

> "The significance of the research," he explained, is that although the
>   cell phone power is low, "electromagnetic radiation can nevertheless
>   have an effect on mental behavior when transmitting at the proper
>   frequency." He finds this fact especially remarkable when considering
>   that everyone is surrounded by electromagnetic clutter radiating from
>   all kinds of electronic devices in our modern world. Cell phones in
>   talk mode seem to be particularly well-tuned to frequencies that
>   affect brainwave activity.

But in terms of mind *control*, the patent does not do anything to support a claim regarding whether or not they can make you do what they want, or feel what they want. If it was indeed possible, then googling for "electromagnetic mind control" should turn up some research papers and not just a bunch of New World Order 911 blogs.

Emotions are way more complicated than "resonances" of "brain circuits". There's a bunch of other stuff going on as well. Hormones play a big role, for example.

Finally: Different TVs will have different electromagnetic signatures, and it'd be next to impossible to get the correct output on all devices embedded in the TV signal. And that's not even accounting for the fact that modern TVs have a much lower EM radiation footprints.

So in conclusion: The patent claims something that it can't deliver on. It's pretty old by now, so we should have been able to see it come to fruition if it would actually work. I mean, if there's a patent, that means the way it works is out in the open. Nothing would stop anyone from building and using such a thing. It combines the correct claim that in-brain EM stimulation can alter behaviour with the correct claim that cell phones and TVs give off EM radiation to arrive at the false claim that you can use the EM radiation from TV or cell phone to alter someone's emotions.

Comment: afaik DBS, or any electrical stimulation techniques for the brain/nervous system don't use *electromagnetic waves* (as in, radiation), it is purely electrical stimulation by forming a closed conductive circuit and making current flow through it. (so actually such stimulation generates an EM field, but it's not the field that is responsible for the effects)

Comment: Also remember, issuance of a patent s no guarantee that the idea _works_, only that an a basic scan did not find evidence of someone parenting it earlier or it otherwise having been anticipated.